# Unity -- Mentioning GUI Element String Length

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Yesterday I have started working on a text based game in Unity, and of course, it is 2D. I have been working with the GUI and I wanted to set a button width to the length of it's string component multiplied by it's font size, which in theory should fit the width perfectly. When I went to the Unity documentation website I found that the string is referenced as text so I tried: `guiStyle * text.Length` which, as you may suspect, didn't work. I of course wont create string variables for this because there will be tons of strings then and I don't just wanna type in times 2. So is there any way of doing this other than just counting the letters or creating lots of strings? Here is
the code:

```
if(GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width * 0.5, Screen.height * 0.5 + normStyle.fontSize, midScreenStyle.fontSize, midScreenStyle.fontSize), "Ok", midScreenStyle))
    beingSure = true;
```

the `normStyle.fontSize` is the fontSize of another GUI element just so they aren't in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

> I have started working on a text based game in Unity

Use the new [UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) if this is a new game. Each image in each button can be modified by changing the properties of the [Image](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) component and this prevents other problems you will be having soon.

Comment: I want the button just to fit the text and I don't wanna try and figure out what the size should be, I want it done automatically, and if I want to make it bigger I can just multiply it by how much I want